# OMEMO encryption in XMPP protocol for chat in iOS

Tags: ios

one to one chat
one to many chat
with using the XMPP protocol.

Need OMEMO Encryption with XMPP protocol for single chat and group chat with complete steps.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your post as a question.  Maybe explain what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

Nonetheless, I'd suggest looking for a XMPP framework to help. The XMPPFramework here should start you in the right direction.  https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: Hi Derek,
Thanks for your answer. I need to know the Configuration step by step process for OMEMO Encryption and DB process.
Need brief explanation about OMEMO Encryption in swift or obj-c

Comment: Hi Derek, Any update?

Comment: Sorry Manikandan, I won't be able to provide a step by step process to implement this for you.  Check out `ChatSecure` and see if that works for you.  Best of luck!

Comment: Okay Derek, let me check.